# Issue with Highcharts master-slave chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I Was checking out the possibility of implementing a zoomable line chart using Highcharts something that highstock line chart does and came across this example in the [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail). This will really work fine for me but I have seen a issue with the chart that When I select complete data in the smaller chart, the Big chart isn't showing anything.

[image: Image captured from its fiddle]

I Want to know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you play with that example and check the JavaScript console for errors, you'll see:

```
Highcharts error #12: www.highcharts.com/errors/12
```

Following that link:

> Highcharts Error #12
>
> Highcharts expects point configuration to be numbers or arrays in
>   turbo mode
>
> This error occurs if the series.data option contains object
>   configurations and the number of points exceeds the turboThreshold. It
>   can be fixed by either setting the turboThreshold option to a higher
>   value, or changing your point configurations to numbers or arrays. See
>   [turboThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold).

Shockingly enough, if increase or disable the `turboThreshold`, the problem goes away.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/uczKn/1/).